# How to insert a value into an existing table record using another table's primary key?

Tags: sql, delphi-2010

I have a table `USERSINFO` with the following columns:

```
Email (primary key)
Name
```

I have another table `USERFAVOURTIES` with the following columns:

```
UserID (primary Key)
Email (foreign Key)
CrushMuseum
```

I want the `CrushMuseum` column's value to change to 'F'.

This must only happen for the current user's Email which is saved as 'sEmail'

Here is my code:

```
qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Clear;
qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Add('INSERT into UserFavourites(Email,CrushMuseum) values((SELECT Email from UsersInfo where Email ='+QuotedStr(sEmail)+', F)');
qryGoldReefCity.ExecSQL;
```

I get a syntax error.

I am a beginner to Delphi so all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO UserFavourites (UserID, Email, CrushMuseum)
SELECT 12345, Email, 'F'
FROM UserInfo
WHERE Email = '+QuotedStr(sEmail)+'
```

The syntax you were using with `VALUES` is typically used when inserting hard-coded constants.  In your case, since you want to insert values from a query, the `SELECT` clause plays the role that `VALUES` would have otherwise.

An update to this answer includes inserting a value for `userID` which is a primary key column and therefore cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: Is this the correct way to write out the code you gave?qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Clear;
 qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Add('Insert INTO UserFavourites(Email,CrushMuseum)');
 qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Add('SELECT Email,F');
 qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Add('FROM UsersInfo');
 qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Add('WHERE Email = '+QuotedStr(sEmail));
 qryGoldReefCity.ExecSQL;

Comment: Does that run without error?  If not, you may need to add some spaces.

Comment: I get an error:"Parameter F has no default value."Where should i add spaces?

Comment: `qryGoldReefCity.SQL.Add('SELECT Email, ''F''');`

Comment: You need to put single quotes around `F`, but you need to also escape the single quotes.  By the way, you should look into using prepared statements beyond this question and answer.

Comment: I get an error:"Index or primary key cannot contain a null value."

Comment: @JDPERUMAL This problem is due to _not_ specifying a `UserID` value when you insert.  The error message is pretty clear about this.  So, also insert a `UserID` value and this error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL syntax would be `insert . . . select`.  Something like this:

```
INSERT into UserFavourites(Email, CrushMuseum) 
    SELECT Email, 'F'
    FROM UsersInfo 
    WHERE Email = '+QuotedStr(sEmail)+'
```